# Http Client POST upload file - MultipartException: Curren t request is not a multipart request

Tags: java, rest, api, http-post, apache-httpclient-4.x

I need to test file upload  using httpclient 4.5

Below method is being used to upload a file:

```
public Response postwithFile(String url, File file) {
        HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(PropertyUtil.loadEnvironment().getBaseUrl() + url);
        postMethod.setHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data");
        FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file, ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
        //_addAuthHeader(postMethod);
        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        // fileParamName should be replaced with parameter name your REST API expect.
        builder.addPart("upfile", fileBody);
        HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
        postMethod.setEntity(entity) ;
        return execute(postMethod);
    }
```

The file do not have any extension but the content of the file is JSON.

On calling above method I receive 500 error with below exception in server logs:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Curren
t request is not a multipart request                                                                                                                            
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
```

Can anyone please help where I am doing wrong?

Comment: [Here](https://memorynotfound.com/apache-httpclient-multipart-upload-request/) is a working example, you can compare your version with that.

Answer (score 1):

Use following

```
 builder.addBinaryBody(
        "upfile",
        new FileInputStream(file),
        ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM,
        file.getName()
    );
```

instead of

```
 builder.addPart("upfile", fileBody);
```

Also following is no longer required as it is also deprecated:-

```
FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file, ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
```

Comment: I am testing using httpclient and this code is part of my automation tests. I am not sure where you are asking me to check this?

Comment: So the code you are invoking is a kind of client and the error is coming on server side. Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Just test once with client like postman to check if server is responding perfectly.

Comment: instead of add part try addBinayBody of multipart. i am editing my answer